# HTTP403 Error with Python goes away after opening link in browser

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to build a web scraper in Python (Python 3). This is the code I'm using to get the webpage from the server

```
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(page_link)) as response:
        if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type'):
            htmlBytes = response.read()
            html = htmlBytes.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

I have made sure that I'm only using valid URLs. The problem I'm facing is that the server returns an HTTP403 error when I run my code. However, if I then open the link on my browser and then run my code, it works fine. I cannot manually go and visit all the links I need to scrape from and then run the code. Can someone point to what the reason might be?

Comment: Try setting a proper User Agent header.